# remove html tags from string using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html

I wonder how could i remove the html tags using htmlagilitypack as below ?

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(Description);
//markups to be removed
var markups = new List<string> { "br","ol","ul","li" };
```

thanks

Comment: is it compulsary to use htmlagilitypack?

Comment: @techloverr, what else are you going to use, [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1043380)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
 public static string RemoveHTMLTags(string content)
        {
            var cleaned = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string textOnly = string.Empty;
                Regex tagRemove = new Regex(@"<[^>]*(>|$)");
                Regex compressSpaces = new Regex(@"[\s\r\n]+");
                textOnly = tagRemove.Replace(content, string.Empty);
                textOnly = compressSpaces.Replace(textOnly, " ");
                cleaned = textOnly;
            }
            catch
            {
                //A tag is probably not closed. fallback to regex string clean.

            }

            return cleaned;
        }
```

Comment: by the way, how do i replace <br> with <br/> ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//markups to be removed
var markups = new List<string> { "br", "ol", "ul", "li" };

var xpath = String.Join(" | ", markups.Select(x => "//" + x));
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
}
```